# How do we avoid crashes in async calls that reference cocos2d-iphone (2.0.0) UI classes?

Tags: multithreading, cocos2d-iphone

In my iOS game with cocos2d-iphone 2.0.0, I have a layer that pops up a sprite that asks the user to buy an in app purchase with a button for the user to click to buy (`menuItemBuyButton`). When user clicks on this buy button, three things are done:

- an activity indicator is started
- all menu items on the layer are disabled - particularly, the main menu (this code is on the main menu scene), the buy button itself and the popup's menu
- the usual sequence of purchase calls and callbacks are triggered.

When the purchase is completed, the callback (which is on another thread) then needs to:

- stop the activity indicator
- reenable the disabled menu elements
- replace the scene with another director

Now, when I run this sequence, and test by clicking on the buy button repeatedly, etc., just once (and unable to repro ever again) I got a crash in the code - the code and crash logs are below. I suspect (and may be wrong) this is due to the un-thread-safe nature of cocos2d. How do I avoid this crash? I do need to disable the UI elements before starting the buy transaction and have to reenable them once the transaction is finished, which will happen in another thread.

Code is as below:

```
-(void) startActivityIndicator {
    mainMenu.enabled = NO;
    scorePopupMenu.enabled = NO;
    menuItemBuyButton.isEnabled = NO;
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}

-(void) stopActivityIndicator {
    mainMenu.enabled = YES;
    scorePopupMenu.enabled = YES;//this is line 744 that crashed
    menuItemBuyButton.isEnabled = YES;
    if (activityIndicatorView.isAnimating)
        [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}
```

Crash logs:

```
5   SmartRun        0x00126c4c -[MainMenuLayer stopActivityIndicator] (MainMenuLayer.m:744)
```

Comment: In which thread is `stopActivityIndicator` called? Background or main?

Answer (score 0):

Then disable repeated tap. Just disable touch once it is pressed and reenable once it is processed.

```
    node.touchEnabled = NO; //do this for all menu and layer

     (In Cocos2d 1.0 isTouchEnabled to NO)
```

We also used inAp purchase in cocos2d game with activity indicator from UIKit. What we did is used activity indicator inside Alert view. That blocks user to do other UI switch.

```
-(void)ShowActivityIndicator
{
    if(!mLoadingView) //    UIAlertView     *mLoadingView;
    {
        mLoadingView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        actInd.frame = CGRectMake(128.0f, 45.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f);
        [mLoadingView addSubview:actInd];
        [actInd startAnimating];
        [actInd release];


        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        l.frame = CGRectMake(100, -25, 210, 100);
        l.text = @"Please wait...";
        l.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        l.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        l.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        l.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [mLoadingView addSubview:l];
        [l release];
    }

    [mLoadingView show];
}

-(void)StopIndicator
{
    [mLoadingView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but adding an alert is not acceptable in my case - I want to be able to do this without any change to the UI.

Comment: then set cocos2d menu's and layer's touchEnabled to NO(In Cocos2d 1.0 isTouchEnabled to NO). This works for sure:)